# Is there any simple algorithm which can tell if a string is a repeat of its substring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algorithms

Is there any simple algorithm which can tell if a string is a repeat of its substring?
For example, $1212121212$ is a repeat of $12$, $135746135746$ is a repeat of $135746$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the string in question and let $n$ be the length of $S$. Consider all prefixes of $S$ whose length divides $n$ (because if the string $S$ is a repeat of string $X$, then the length of $X$ must divides $n$). For each of these prefixes, check if $S$ is a repeat of this prefix (which can be done trivially in $O(n)$). How fast is this algorithm?

Let $\sigma_0(n)$ be the number of divisors of $n$ (see [Divisor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)). This algorithm thus works in $O(\sigma_0(n) \cdot n)$. Furthermore, it is known that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\sigma_0(n) = o(n^\epsilon)$, and thus, this algorithm, despite being simple, is quite fast!

Comment: +1 I think it's even faster than that on average. Rather that running through all divisors, you could just run through the coefficients of prime divisors. For example in a string of $12$ characters, checking whether or not the first $6$ ($12/2$) repeat and whether or not the first $4$ ($12/3$) repeat is enough to know whether or not there is repetition. So you can replace $\sigma_o(n)$ with the number of prime divisors of $n$, $\omega(n)$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Nice observation! I will amend the answer.

Comment: Wait, that doesn't quite work the way you said it. I would say look at (abcdef)(ghijkl) and (abcd)(efgh)(ijkl). The way you have said it, you look at (ab)(cd)(ef)(gh)(ij)(kl) and (abc)(def)(ghi)(jkl), which would not see that 123456123456 is a repeat.

Comment: Don't you have to factorize $n$ anyway? You can't run through the divisors counted by $\sigma_0(n)$ without a factorization.

Comment: It would be $\sum_{p|n}(\text{time to compare prefix of length n/p to the other p-1 chunks})$ The sum has $\omega(n)$ terms. It's hard to say if there is or isn't a clever fast way to make the comparisons, but $O(n)$ is at least an upper bound.

Comment: @alex.jordan There is actually, using suffix trees. But since the OP wants a simple algorithm, I didn't want to clutter the description.

Comment: $O(n\omega(n))$ is at worst an upper bound, (plus the time to factor $n$ though, which is a burden). And $\omega(n)\tilde{}\ln\ln(n)$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Note that the time required to factor $n$ is easily $O(n)$ (try all numbers between $1$ and $n$), and since we already have the algorithm to be $\Omega(n)$ anyway... (I realized this a little late as well)

Answer (score 0):

It is not mathematic point of view, but you are probably do not expect such a restriction. There exists Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm, checking occurences of given string. One can adapt it to your problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
def isRepeating(s):
    for l in range(1, len(s)//2 +1):
        if len(s) % l != 0:
            continue
        if containsRepeatingSubstring(s, l):
            return True
    return False

def containsRepeatingSubstring(s, l):
    for i in range(l, len(s)):
        if s[i] != s[i % l]:
            return False
    return True
```